# AWS Cognito verification email not received by user account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

While creating user in userpool, user invitation messages are sent with a temporary password but email verification messages is not being sent.
I was creating a very simple setup to try out aws cognito service.
Here is what I did in AWS cognito, I created a user pool with step by step as follows:
1)What do you want to name your user pool?
-> testpool
2)How do you want to create your user pool?
-> step through settings
3)How do you want your end users to sign in?
->Email address or phone number-Allow email addresses
4)What password strength do you want to require?
->Minimum length=6
5)Do you want to allow users to sign themselves up?
->Allow users to sign themselves up
6)How quickly should user accounts created by administrators expire if not used?
->Days to expire-7
7)Do you want to enable Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)?
->off
8)Do you want to require verification of emails or phone numbers?
->Email
9)You must provide a role to allow Amazon Cognito to send SMS messages
->testpool-SMS-Role
10)Do you want to customize your email verification messages?
->Verification type-link
->Email subject = Your verification link
->Email message = Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##}
11)Do you want to customize your user invitation messages?
->SMS message = Your username is {username} and temporary password is ->{####}. 
->Email subject = Your temporary password
->Email message = Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. 
12)Do you want to customize your email address?
->no
13)Do you want to add tags for this user pool?
->no
14)Do you want to remember your user's devices?
->no
15)Which app clients will have access to this user pool?
->none(will simulate from create user option in genral setting-user and group)
16)Do you want to customize workflows with triggers?
->no
17)Review page - this page shows summary of whatever I selected
**Create pool**

Now after pool creation went ot genral setting-user and group and clicked **create user**
A Create user pop-up shows:
Username (Required): myEmailAddress
Send an invitation to this new user?: check
Temporary password: left blank
Phone Number: empty(not required)
Mark phone number as verified? unCheck 
Email: myEmailAddress 
Mark email as verified? unCheck 
Click on Create User

A mail is received into my account form no-reply@verificationemail.com via amazonses.com,
with subject: Your temporary password
 with message as: Your username is somemailid@gmail.com and temporary password is agsjyk.

This is okay.

But I didnot receive any verification mail link before previous mail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if you're missing this particular setup....Domain name is require for link verification.
Under "Tab integration" then "Domain name"

Comment: still facing issue

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm experiencing same issue and I had already verified domain.

Comment: @openwonk probably late on reply but you would need to add email as verification method as stated below

Answer (score 7):

> A mail is received into my account form no-reply@verificationemail.com via
>   amazonses.com,
>   with subject: Your temporary password
>   with message as: Your username is somemailid@gmail.com and temporary password is > agsjyk.

Looking at this it seems you are creating the user via the Cognito API by the AdminCreateUser method, and that's why you are receiving a temporary password.

The confirmation email you are expecting will only be sent if the user registers itself, so you should use the SignUp method.

Comment: Thanks mate, almost 3 years later this comes handy, trapped myself using the wrong method.

Answer (score 2):

With Cognito, if you have added both email and phone number then you should allow both as verification methods(In the SignUp experience Tab) as below:
[image: Attribute Verification and Account Confirmation]

Otherwise the email verification link or code is not sent

Answer (score 1):

verification mail link is for when users sign themselves up, they will receive a link to ask them to verify the email address instead of a code. In your case, you are send a temporary password to the user, so the link wont show up.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. Actually as you can see in point number 10 - i choose verification type as link. Also I wanted to know if this is only posible if we use SES api for sending verification link and storing all the email(of my app users) there itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a domain in this section of the Incognito Service:

[image]

Also, if you are not getting the email, click on the user, and check their email, it could be wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is facing this issue, it appears that you cannot send verification emails if you use SAML or a federated identity provider. Cognito sets the cognito user to EXTERNAL_PROVIDER and no Cognito API calls allow sending a verifcation code or link. The cognito user is automatically created on initial sign-in. I have my user pool set to validate email address but it is always set to false.

The only way that I know to confirm the user via SSO is to use an external verification process outside of cognito.